# Call method from list of multiple objects with list of multiple arguments

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, lambda, functional-programming

I'm working with Tkinter in Python, and I created multiple TextWidgets.
I put these Objects in a list called output.
Each text widget has the property text, which can be changed with the methods .delete(index1,index2) and insert(index, chars).

Now, I'd like to apply the **insert** function. From another fuction kg_to_pounds_ounces_grams I get a list of values for the Text Widgets:

```
def kg_to_pounds_ounces_grams(kilogram):
    pound = kilogram * 2.20462
    oounce = kilogram * 35.274
    gram = kilogram * 1000
    return [pound, oounce, gram]
```

How can I apply insert to Output so that pound goes into TextWidget1, ounce into TextWidget2 and gram into TextWidget3, and call the function kg_to_pounds_ounces_grams only one time in a one line expression?
Same goes for delte - also applied to all in one line?

Edit:
I managed to do both in three lines:

```
for textWidget,weight  in zip(output, kg_to_pounds_ounces_grams(kg) ):
    textWidget.delete(1.0, END)
    textWidget.insert(END,weight)
```

But it still bothers me - is there no elegant two-line solution?

For better understanding, I put the full code here:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()


def kg_to_pounds_ounces_grams(kilogram):
    pound = kilogram * 2.20462
    ounce = kilogram * 35.274
    gram = kilogram * 1000
    return [pound, ounce, gram]


def convert_button_pressed():
    try:
        kg = float(e1_text.get())
    except:
        kg = float("NaN")
    map(lambda x: x.delete(1.0, END), output)
    # Missing Code goes here!


l1 = Label(window, text="Kg")
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

e1_text = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(window, textvariable=e1_text)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

b1 = Button(window, text="Convert", command=convert_button_pressed)
b1.grid(row=0, column=2)

t1 = Text(window, height=1, width=20)
t1.grid(row=1, column=0)

t2 = Text(window, height=1, width=20)
t2.grid(row=1, column=1)

t3 = Text(window, height=1, width=20)
t3.grid(row=1, column=2)

output = [t1, t2, t3]

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm sure, it's possible by using map, lambda and for in the right way.
My last (failed) try looks like this:
`map(lambda x: x.insert(END,out) for out in kg_to_pounds_ounces_grams(kg), output)`

Comment: why is it important to have a two-line solution? Trying to condense the code down will only serve to make it harder to read and harder to debug.

Comment: Are you simply wanting to insert the three values returned by the function? What's wrong with simply joining the results into a string and inserting the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to your `delete` line you can do the insert in a single line... but for readability's sake I wouldn't recommend these one-liners.

It should be noted that using lambda in conjuction with map is a bit silly, a list comprehension would be cleaner:

```
[x.delete(1.0, END) for xin output]
```

And for the insert:

```
[x.insert(END, w) for x, w in zip(output, kg_to_pound_ounces_grams(kg))]
```

I suppose you could even combine them, but once again I don't recommend either of these.

```
[(x.delete(1.0, END), x.insert(END, w)) for x, w in zip(output, kg_to_pound_ounces_grams(kg))]
```